# Job submission in SLURM

Tags: bash, performance, slurm, hpc, sbatch

I am trying to use all the nodes but not able to do so. As CPU load is always around 0.1-0.5. where am i going wrong?

[image]

My job is at node 7

```
#script
#!/bin/bash
#BATCH --job-name=atg7-3-7-3
#SBATCH --output=atg7-3-7-3.out
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=40
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=128GB
#SBATCH --partition=compute
```

Other jobs go around 40 to 100. I want to run it at 100 percent of its computing capacity.
I am new to slurm.

Comment: The remaining of the submission script would be necessary to understand what is happening. The show section only concern the resource request, not the resource usage.